# Unable to call sync function inside service from controller in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to call async function defined in service for fetching data from database.I am calling from controller but its not returning any data but when I am doing exactly same code inside controller its returning data.

Its showing my this inside controller on doing console.log:

"Inside controller":  [AsyncFunction: fetchReviews]

Below is my code:

**constroller.js**

```
const {fetchReviews}  = require('../services/getReviews.service');

const getReviews = async (req,res) => {
  const data = await fetchReviews;
  console.log("Inside controller:",data);
  return res.status(200).send({"reviews": data });
}
```

**getreviews.service.js**

```
const reviews = require('../db/reviewSchema');

const fetchReviews = async () => {
  const allReviews = await reviews.find({});
  const count = allReviews.length;
  console.log("Inside service",count);
  return allReviews;
}

module.exports = {fetchReviews};
```

Even the `console.log()` statement is not showing inside service.What could be the cause any help.

Comment: `fetchReviews` is a function .... you need to call a function ... e.g. `const data = await fetchReviews();`

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning `fetchReviews` function to `data` variable. You should have called/invoked it there.

```
const getReviews = async (req,res) => {
  const data = await fetchReviews(); // Invoked the function
  console.log("Inside controller:",data);
  return res.status(200).send({"reviews": data });
}
```